# No html building from Markdown with jekyll - github pages

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I set up a local repository customized with some jekyll template and then configured a git repository syncronized with a github account.

All works perfectly: running

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

on my pc, I can see a preview of the website.

After pushing all the changes to github, I can see my website running.

All is correctly working **except** for one thing, the **post pages edited in Markdown**.

While with `jekyll serve --watch` I can see a correct preview of the page (with headers, images...) when pushing to github, it seems that the *real* website doesn't interpret correctly the Markdown syntax.

The result is that I see Markdown just as simple line text and not formatted (no images, no headers...)

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds a bit like a bug that I've encountered before. Back then, I fixed it by adding the `markdownify` filter (`{{ content | markdownify }}`). If that doesn't fix it, can you post a link to your repo?

Comment: here it is https://github.com/ghtmtt/ghtmtt.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `_layouts/post.html` template you are printing `{{ page.content }}` which is the un-rendered content, the markdown.

From within a template, the rendered content is in the `{{ content }}` variable.

Comment: Oh thanks! Added the changes, push them and now it seems that all is correctly compiled!